# icacls to make folder read-only

Tags: icacls

I'm just learning about icacls to set permissions to a folder.  Better yet, I want to make sure that a folder is readonly.  Anyone have any ideas?

C:>icacls.exe C:\TEMP\Reports [switches]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?  Try searching the site, there are many [icacls examples](https://serverfault.com/search?q=icacls).

```
REM take ownership and reset permissions
TAKEOWN /f "C:\TEMP\Reports" /r /d y
ICACLS "C:\TEMP\Reports" /reset /T
REM grant full control to administrators, read only to everyone else
ICACLS "C:\TEMP\Reports" /grant:r "BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS":(OI)(CI)F ^
                         /grant:r "BUILTIN\EVERYONE":(OI)(CI)R ^
REM set inheritance on everything below
ICACLS "C:\TEMP\Reports" /inheritance:r
```